# Lua/Corona SDK: Why is my countdown stopping?

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

I'm programming an app where when you tap a button, it increases time left on a countdown timer and also increases the number on a counter showing how many taps you have made. My problem is that when the two numbers become equal the countdown stops and the number and counter become synonymous. What do I need to change/ what am I doing wrong?

```
-- Create Button
local blueButton = display.newCircle (160,240,45)
blueButton:setFillColor(0,.5,1)

-- Create Tap-counter
local number = 0
local textField = display.newText(number, 160, 30, native.systemFont, 52)

-- Create Countdown Timer
local count = 20
local textCount = display.newText(count, 160, 70, native.systemFont, 52)
textCount:setFillColor(0,1,.25)

-- Create countdown function
local function countDown()
    count = count - 1
    textCount:removeSelf()
    textCount = display.newText(count, 160, 70, native.systemFont, 52)
    textCount:setFillColor(0,1,.25)
end


-- Create tap function
local function buttonTap(event)
    number = number + 1
    textField:removeSelf()
    textField = display.newText(number, 160, 30, native.systemFont, 52)

    count = count + 1
    textCount:removeSelf()
    textCount = display.newText(count, 160, 70, native.systemFont, 52)
    textCount:setFillColor(0,1,.25)
end


-- Tapping button calls tap function 
blueButton:addEventListener("tap", buttonTap)

-- countdown every second
timer.performWithDelay(1000, countDown, count)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want count down to 0 you need set up infinite number of iterations of timer. This is why I use -1 as last argument for timer.

Second, you don't need create new text object after each iteration. Just change text on it.

More information about timer you find in [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/index.html).

Try

```
-- Create Button
local blueButton = display.newCircle (160,240,45)
blueButton:setFillColor(0,.5,1)

-- Create Tap-counter
local number = 0
local textField = display.newText(number, 160, 30, native.systemFont, 52)

-- Create Countdown Timer
local count = 20
local textCount = display.newText(count, 160, 70, native.systemFont, 52)
textCount:setFillColor(0,1,.25)

local myTimer

-- Create countdown function
local function countDown()
    count = count - 1
    textCount.text = count
    if ( count < 1 ) then -- so count = 0 if true
        timer.cancel( myTimer )
    end 
end


-- Create tap function
local function buttonTap(event)
    number = number + 1
    textField.text = number

    count = count + 1
    textCount.text = count
end


-- Tapping button calls tap function 
blueButton:addEventListener("tap", buttonTap)

-- countdown every second
myTimer = timer.performWithDelay(1000, countDown, -1)
```